# Is it ok to repeat same word in a row in sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-usage, comparison

Is it ok to repeat words in a sentence? or **Is only specific in poetry?**

Research says It's used to stress

1. key points,
2. to achieve a certain rhythm, tone,
3. or style of prose.

For Instance!

> Perhaps, perhaps, perhaps
>
> because because.

Also, Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Such usages are effectively "extra-grammatical". By which I mean the concept of "grammatically / syntactically **valid**" can't meaningfully be applied to them. Apart from being a famous (Doris Day?) song, I don't know what ***Perhaps, perhaps, perhaps*** means (I assume that in the song it's a combination of "emphasis" and "scansion"). But ***Because because*** is an idiomatically established utterance that normally means *Because **I say so**, and I don't wish to / can't explain any further* (or it's a resigned *Because that's just the way things are*).

Comment: Linguistically speaking, it's called [***reduplication***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication) But the "device" occurs in a wide range of contexts with different justifications and intended meanings - most of which should probably be avoided by learners / non-native speakers, because the chances are that exactly how it works in *their* language won't be the same as in English. So learners *will* make mistakes, which may or may not be highly noticeable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Those 2 comments constitute quite a good answer. Why not convert them to one?

Comment: @PeterJennings: I voted to close for **Needs details or clarity**. OP's two examples are completely different, and I suspect *neither* of them are "typical" examples of (whole word) reduplication from a linguist's perspective. Effectively, my comments are intended to explain why this isn't a good question for this site, not to actually *answer* the question!

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?) [Contrastive focus reduplication](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112528/contrastive-focus-reduplication)

Comment: If your research says it's a 'style of prose', it obviously isn't limited to poetry! The main use is for emphasis in informal use - "The insect was very, very small" - "It's a big, big world".

Comment: @KateBunting. Those two examples are really looks to me poetry style. If I want to say something so small/big, can I not say in other word. I am not sure just learner.

Comment: _Very very_ is an informal way of emphasising an adjective; in more formal language we would probably say _extremely small_. Nothing poetic about it. [This Ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22big%20big%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) shows that _big, big_ occurs mostly in children's books. Adults would usually say _very big, huge, enormous_ etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers as you mentioned wide range of contexts with different justifications and intended meanings. It's so complex understanding for me but you explained so well. I have same understanding as explained "mostly in children' books".

Comment: Well, there's *education, education, education* and *location, location, location*, which ***only*** underline the importance of the word. But ***rabbit rabbit*** and ***rhubarb rhubarb***, (non-stop and/or background nattering) are very different usages that are *always* repeated in certain contexts, but have little to do with "emphasis". And there are plenty more "distinct" repeated usages where the meaning is *different*, not just *emphatic*.

Comment: Then, we do say "had had," as in "I had had a cold, but am feeling better." Or, "that that," as in "That *that* car is overpriced is not under discussion," the second that pointing to a particular car. Well, well, there do seem to be repeated words! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences for more. ;-)